# Using C++ macros to register a template class and an alias

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following code.

```
namespace foo{
template <typename A>
struct Foo{};
}

struct Bar{};

struct Baz{};
```

And I want to write a macro `CREATE` that creates a new *CustomName1Type* class and *CustomName2Type* class.

```
#define CREATE(custom_name, struct_name)         \
template class foo::Foo<struct_name>;            \ 
using #custom_name##Type = foo::Foo<struct_name>;

CREATE(CustomName1, Bar)
CREATE(CustomName2, Baz)
```

Equating to

```
template class foo::Foo<Bar>;
using CustomName1Type = foo::Foo<Bar>;

template class foo::Foo<Baz>;
using CustomName2Type = foo::Foo<Baz>;
```

How can I modify `CREATE` to do this? Also, what is the style guide requirement and the position for writing such a macro?

Comment: What is wrong with your macro? From a glance it seems to me that only the `#` at the beginning doesn't belong there. Also, why do you need the explicit instantiations? They should appear only in one translation unit, but you are probably intending to use the alias in multiple.

Comment: Thanks @user17732522. That seemed to fix it. Its just so hard debugging macros and no good resource out there. Preprocessor directives are usually a C thing which is why I thought tagging C should be fine.

Comment: Also can you answer the style guide aspect if possible?

Comment: I would first need to understand the purpose of this. It is usually not necessary to explicitly instantiate and I don't know how it goes together with the alias. See my edited comment above.

Comment: I'm using this way to create multiple classes like Foo that depend on the Bar, Baz etc types.

Comment: I think I need the explicit instantiation to create the alias?

Comment: No, that is not what explicit instantiation is for. You can just declare the alias or use e.g. `foo::Foo<Baz>` directly where you would use `CustomName2Type`. For declaring the alias a macro is overkill. Just write out the alias declarations manually.

Comment: Not if the class names are pretty long, incomprehensible and used multiple times. I just had a toy example over here.

Comment: The style guide is: __don't__. Macros aren't a substitution for some typing and a more capable code editor.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i Modify `CREATE` to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

#define JOIN(A, B) A##B

#define CREATE(custom_name, struct_name) \
template class foo::Foo<struct_name>; \
using JOIN(custom_name, Type) = foo::Foo<struct_name>; 

namespace foo{
template <typename A>
struct Foo{};
}

struct Bar {};

struct Baz {};

CREATE(CustomName1, Bar)
CREATE(CustomName2, Baz)

int main() {

  cout << is_same<CustomName1Type, foo::Foo<Bar>>::value << endl;
  cout << is_same<CustomName2Type, foo::Foo<Baz>>::value << endl;
}
```

> Also, what is the style guide requirement and the position for writing such a macro?

I don't understand this part, but I think it's referring to why your macro doesn't work (if i'm wrong, plz tell me that i will edit the answer)

---

The problem is: `using #custom_name##Type = foo::Foo<struct_name>;`

Because you dont have any parameter named Type, see the example below:

```
#define CONCAT1(A, B) A##B -> This will join A and B

#define CONCAT2(A, B) #A -> This will replace A parameter as caractere ("")

#define CONCAT3(A, B) #A#B -> This will join A and B parameter as caractere ("")

int main(){
  int MyValue = 100;
  cout << CONCAT1(My, Value) << endl; //cout << MyValue << endl

  cout << CONCAT2(My, Value) << endl; //cout << "My" << endl

  cout << CONCAT3(My, Value) << endl; //cout << "MyValue" << endl
}
```

Result: 
100 
My 
MyValue